# How to submit pull request separately?

Tags: git, github

I have 1 folder contained 20 .doc file. I want to separate 10 each for 2 different pull request. I created different branch for it. I submitted first one, but when I submitted second pull request it seems the 1st commit of 1st PR is appended to 2nd PR. So how to separate between 2 PR?

Comment: Checkout to 1 branch, git add file_name, git commit -m "commit-message" , git push. Now pull the updated version and checkout to 2branch and repeat the step.

Comment: Thanks @Gosi. I just read it however, I tried another way. I use git stash command and it works!

Comment: Glad it worked for you!